# Website Access Active Directory

Tags: gmail

A client has an Active Directory Domain named anycomp.com and hosts their website www.anycomp.com with an external offsite ISP. Clients on the internal Active Directory Domain need access to the website but are unable to resolve the name www.anycomp.com in their browsers. What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Add a DNS A record for `www` in the AD anycomp.com DNS zone for the external ip address of the website.